# Java inheritance with List Objects

Tags: java, inheritance

In this basic example

```
String str = "hola";
Object o;

o = str; // it's OK

List<String> listado = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Object> listResult;

listResult = listado; // it's WRONG
```

why the cast to the superclass works in the first case but doesn't work when working with Lists? (It gives a *Type mismatch: cannot convert from List< String> to List< Object>*)

Comment: that would allow you to add `Object`s to `listado`, which can only take `String`.

Comment: `List<? extends Object> listResult = listado;` would work. For an explanation see [the official Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html)

Comment: Thanks, in the link is very well explained